# How to Use QTimer With a QWidget (if possible)

Tags: python, pyqt, countdowntimer, qtimer

I need some help figuring out how to create a timer under a widget class.  I've got the following class:

```
class TimerClass(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(TimerClass, self).__init__()
```

and I'm trying to implement a timer as follows:

```
def start_timer(self):
    timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
    timer.timeout.connect(self.__Time)
    timer.start(1000)
```

and it calls the following:

```
def __Time(self):
    print("Timer End")
```

This QWidget is called from my MainWindow and I have another timer that works without a problem as shown above with MainWindow but I can't figure out how to get it to work with QWidget.  I assume the use of QWidget is the problem because I get the following error when I try and run it:

> AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute '_TimerClass__Time'

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what the proper way of doing this would be?

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It seems like the code that is causing the Error is not the one you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get that error from the code you've posted, is if the `MainWindow` class inherits the `TimerClass`, and then an instance of `MainWindow` tries to call `self.__Time()`.

That cannot work, because [double-underscored attributes](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) are only directly accessible to the class that defines them. If you rename the method to have only one underscore, the error will go away.

However, using multiple inheritance with `QObject` subclasses (such as `QWidget`) is generally a bad idea, and should be avoided. Use [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) instead.